# Apple Push Notifications Service ( APNS ): Feedback Service Response has missing byte?

Tags: java, ruby, sockets, apple-push-notifications, push-notification

I am writing a push notifications system in Ruby. Sending the notifications using the enhanced interface works fine, consuming from the Feedback Service is not working at all.

I wrote the code to read from the socket myself, something like this:

```
      context      = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
      context.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read(pem_path))
      context.key  = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read(rsa_path))
      @socket = TCPSocket.new(host, port)
      @ssl    = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(@socket, context)
      @ssl.connect
      @socket.gets #read(38) has the same effect FWIW
```

But the APNS Feedback Service returns only 37 bytes instead of the expected 38, and as expected the package is messes up.

I can replicate the error using the Ruby [APNS gem](https://github.com/jpoz/APNS/blob/master/lib/apns/core.rb) (and openened a ticket for them [here](https://github.com/jpoz/APNS/issues/8#issuecomment-3160979)).

I've saved all I receive from the APNS Feedback Service to a file and here's what I get when trying to inspect the bytes:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :035 > while b = f.readbyte
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :036?>   puts b
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :037?>   end
21
3
1
0
32
23
35
236
232
217
53
172
143
54
130
39
157
247
205
233
231
245
140
111
104
199
214
159
60
107
169
175
42
172
57
31
160
```

As you can see, the array is off by one, is should look like this:
[image: APNS Feedback Format]

Anyone had similar issues or can see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT @ 19/2011:**

This seems to be an issue with Ruby sockets. Using the [java-apns lib](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns) the following Clojure core returns the expected result for the same application, certificates and etc.

```
(def tokens (. (.. (APNS/newService) 
                   (withCert "/Users/pcalcado/blah.p12" "blah") 
                   withProductionDestination 
                   build) 
               getInactiveDevices))
```

I cannot see anything special [being done by java-apns](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns/blob/master/src/main/java/com/notnoop/apns/internal/ApnsFeedbackConnection.java) or what I could be doing wrong in Ruby. I wouldn't mind using Clojure for this system but now I have everything but Feedback already written and running in Ruby on MRI =/

Answer (score 2):

I asking myself... is it possible we have to read from @ssl instead of @socket?
Sorry but I am a bit n00b about Ruby programming :)

**Edit**:
I confirm you the problem is that you need to read from SSL socket
Look at this commit: https://github.com/muccy/APNS/commit/4d62a3f33c4b31f7f81a0020aa70871232f46781

Comment: Spot on. I changed to read from the SSL when I first saw your comment but didn't have time to actually tty it out before xmas, tried now and it works. Thanks, mate.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [APND gem](https://github.com/itspriddle/apnd) by Josh Priddle. I used it successfully, and believe its core functionality, which includes retrieving feedback from Apple, works as it should. If for nothing else, it's another code example -- in Ruby -- for you to examine.